# Firmware error in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel, firmware

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 in BenQ Joybook Lite UI05, it starts and works normally on live boot. After restarting when installation completed it works inconsistently i.e takes too longer time to return to home screen. I found following error lines in  Kernel Log under /var/log/kern.log. Below is the portion for Kernel log.

> Apr  5 08:52:27 cclab kernel: [    0.184048] pci 0000:00:1f.0:
>   [Firmware Bug]: TigerPoint LPC.BM_STS cleared Apr  5 08:52:32 cclab
>   kernel: [   68.915553] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode15.fw"
>   not found Apr  5 08:52:32 cclab kernel: [   68.915557] b43-phy0 ERROR:
>   Firmware file "b43-open/ucode15.fw" not found Apr  5 08:52:32 cclab
>   kernel: [   68.915562] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to
>   http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and
>   download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please
>   carefully read all instructions on this website.

and under /var/log/dmesg.0 nothing has recorded.

> (Nothing has been logged yet.)

Thanks in advance for working answer.

Comment: Did you do what the message told you to do?